# Extract found value and its indexes from nested array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Example data with nested arrays:

```
[
  {
    "rows": [["123", "234", "345"], ["345", "456", "567"]]
  },
  {
    "rows": [["111", "222", "333"], ["444", "555", "345"]]
  },
]
```

Given a specific value (e.g. `345`), I want to aggregate into the results the found value, with its first array index (e.g. `row_i`), and its second array index (e.g. `col_i`):

```
[
  {"value": "345", "row_i": 0, "col_i": 2},
  {"value": "345", "row_i": 1, "col_i": 0},
  {"value": "345", "row_i": 1, "col_i": 2},
]
```

I know how to aggregate the whole document with `$elemMatch` ([Example 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-bMFKIdOXC-)), but this doesn't include the row/column indexes.

I tried using `$unwind`, but could only make it work with nested objects, not arrays  ([Example 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/llZA_YqYRGT)). I have a limitation where I can't change the data structure at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$unwind` with `includeArrayIndex` twice to create the `row_i` and `col_i` fields.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$rows",
      includeArrayIndex: "row_i"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$rows",
      includeArrayIndex: "col_i"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "rows": "345"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "value": "$rows",
      "row_i": 1,
      "col_i": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LytAImRBRgv)